# How to make Wine open links without IE7

Tags: linux, internet-explorer, wine

I run QQ2012 using Wine, and when I didn't have IE7  installed, the links would open using Chrome. After I installed IE7, links were opened with that.

There's a problem with Explorer too: I don't want to use Wine's Explorer to open directories. I want to use Caja – the Linux native explorer.

Can Wine launch a native Linux program?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
[Software\\Classes\\http\\shell\\open\\command] 1328592010
@="\"C:\\windows\\system32\\winebrowser.exe\" -nohome"

[Software\\Classes\\https\\shell\\open\\command] 1328591981
@="\"C:\\windows\\system32\\winebrowser.exe\" -nohome"

[Software\\Classes\\mailto\\shell\\open\\command] 1328580340
@="C:\\windows\\system32\\winebrowser %1"
```